# Webpack - different font path for build and production css in the less-loader

Tags: webpack, less, webpack-file-loader, less-loader, resolve-url-loader

I'm trying to create an CSS from LESS with webpack. My source folder have following hierarchy:

```
fonts
  desyrel
    desyrel_-webfont.woff
less
  ds-handwritten.less
```

Content of less file include relative font path, which will be used in the production

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
  font-family: 'desyrelregular';
  src: url('/www/fonts/desyrel/desyrel_-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

//DS hand written
.ds-hw { font-family: 'desyrelregular', sans-serif !important; }
```

My entry script is following:

```js
import 'ds-less/ds-handwritten.less';
```

When I'm trying to run the webpack script, I'm receiving following error:

> Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: Can't resolve
> '/www/fonts/desyrel/desyrel_-webfont.woff' in ''

How can I inform webpack, that the relative path of font '/www/fonts/desyrel/desyrel_-webfont.woff' points to font from source path: 'src/fonts/desyrel/desyrel_-webfont.woff'?

I tried to handle the issue with file-loader combined with resolve-url-loader (following the hint from official docu https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url), but without success.

```json
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fonts'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'www/fonts/',
                        esModule: false
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                strictMath: true,
                            },
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to:

- ignore urls in CSS-loader (url: false)
- avoid resolving urls with resolve-url-loader

```json
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fonts'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'fonts/',
                        esModule: false
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                strictMath: true,
                            },
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
```